# List the tables used by the sql script, and the nature of access to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script with thousand of lines and I want to extract all the tables (& temp tables) the script references, and also the nature of access to the table such as select, insert, update or delete. Is there a tool we can use for this purpose?

Sample script (input):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UPDATE Table1 SET Col1 = 1
DELETE FROM Table2
EXEC 'INSERT INTO @Table3 SELECT ''Test'''
```

Sample output:

```
1. Table1 - select, update
2. Table2 - delete
3. @Table3 - insert
```

Comment: The execution plan XML will have all this information easily accesible

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following query useful, however, one thing it doesn't give you is the references from dynamic SQL statements (and perhaps also table variables and temp tables).

I think to get the level of information you're looking for you'd probably need to write your own script/program. Previously I wrote something that gave me the results from the below query, including any dynamic SQL references, in C# using [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(D.referencing_id) referencing_object_schema
    , OBJECT_NAME(D.referencing_id) referencing_object_name
    , O.[type_desc] referencing_object_type
    , D.referenced_schema_name
    , D.referenced_entity_name
    , D.referenced_id
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN O_REF.[object_id] IS NOT NULL THEN O_REF.[type_desc]
            WHEN T.user_type_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'USER_DEFINED_TYPE'
        END referenced_object_type
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies D
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects O ON D.referencing_id = O.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects O_REF ON D.referenced_id = O_REF.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.types T ON D.referenced_id = T.user_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a system function called: fn_dblog. You could use it as below:

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLog') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempLog

  -- Raw Data

    SELECT DISTINCT
    [AllocUnitName],
    Operation
    INTO #tempLog
    FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
    WHERE Operation IN ('LOP_INSERT_ROWS','LOP_MODIFY_ROW',
                        'LOP_DELETE_ROWS','LOP_BEGIN_XACT','LOP_COMMIT_XACT')  
    AND [AllocUnitName] is not null
    ORDER By [AllocUnitName], Operation

    -- SELECT * FROM #tempLog

  -- Display Enhancement and Grouping

    SELECT [AllocUnitName], Operations = STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + REPLACE(operation,'LOP_', '') 
        FROM #tempLog
        WHERE [AllocUnitName] = x.[AllocUnitName]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
    FROM #tempLog AS x
    WHERE [AllocUnitName] is not null
    GROUP BY [AllocUnitName]
    ORDER BY [AllocUnitName]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I tried to run it: 'The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'fn_dblog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.'

Comment: @ricsierics you do not have permission to read from it. Login as an administrator or give permission to the current one.

Comment: I cannot due to my role limitation. I guess it doesn't have to be an administrator to accomplish this task